# django related question querying list of won items by getting list of items then max bid from bid table for each item then check if user won it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a question here, I have two tables in my django models one for listings and one for bids

```
class Listing(models.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Listing'
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField()
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
image = models.URLField(max_length=500, default='')
category = models.CharField(max_length=32)
created = models.CharField(max_length=32)
addedon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Bid(models.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Bid'

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
item = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

what i want is to show a page with all the user won items

```
 def won(request):
listing = Listing.objects.filter(active=False)
```

the question here how i can make list of all then check max bid of each listing, then check is the current user is the winner and display it in the template won.html
like :

```
 getMaxBid = Bid.objects.filter(item_id=listing.id).aggregate(Max('bid'))
            maxBid = getMaxBid['bid__max']
```

then if the user is the winner display it

```
return render(request, "auctions/won.html", {
    'listing': listing, 'active': False
})
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the `Listing` by first creating a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) that will obtain the winner, and then check if the logged in user (or another user) is the winner, so:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

listing = Listing.objects.alias(
    bid_winner=Subquery(
        Bid.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-bid').values('user')
    )[:1]
).filter(
    active=False,
    bid_winner=request.user
)
```

or `Listing`s where the user has an active bid:

```
Listing.objects.filter(
    bid__user=request.user,
    active=True
).distinct()
```

Comment: thanks Willem Van Onsem, thats what i was looking for, just i got an error so modified to  listing = Listing.objects.alias(
    bider=Subquery(Bid.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk')).values('user')
    [:1])
    ).filter(
    active=True,
    bider=request.user
    )

Comment: @cocojumbo: what error...

Comment: another question is i want the same code to request if the user has bid on active item ( any bid and not the max bid ), how can this be done? i tried to remove the .order_by('bid') however not working listing = Listing.objects.alias(
    bider=Subquery(Bid.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk')).values('user')
    [:1])
    ).filter(
    active=True,
    bider=request.user
    )

Comment: @cocojumbo: see edit. In that case you can simply filter with `bid__user=request.user`.